# ¿Cómo inserto un etiqueta HTML dentro de Value de un input?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Soy estudiante y sucede lo siguiente, quiero colocar una etiqueta `<span></span>` dentro de la propiedad `value` de un `input type="submit"`

El principal problema es que al tratar de colocar o imprimir la etiqueta `span` dentro del atributo `value"Texto"`, se muestra la clase de manera escrita dentro del botón, y no el icono que deseo colocar.

Esto lo quiero hacer dado que quiero insertar un icono mediante una etiqueta `<span>` dentro del atributo de `Value`

```
<span class="icon-database"></span><input type="submit" value="Guardar">
```

Entonces, deseo que la clase `icon-database` se agregue de alguna manera dentro de `value="Guardar"` para que se agregue el icono a mi botón.

Tratar de hacer esto pero de manera correcta y que lo interprete el navegador:

```
<input type="submit" value="<span class="icon-database"></span>Guardar">
```

Para darme a entender mejor dejo una imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El icono que se encuentra a la izquierda quiero colocarlo dentro del botón, justo al lado del texto `Guardar`

Se que es una pregunta tonta para muchos pero yo me estoy iniciando en esto y no se la manera de realizarlo todavía.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para el `input` puede emplear los [caracteres](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/) especificados para añadir indirectamente el icono al `value` del `input` , además se puede hacer uso de otras clases para dar un mejor diseño *es obligatorio el uso de fa class*

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<input type="submit" class="fa  btn btn-primary" value="&#xf1c0; Guardar"/>

<input type="submit" class="fa  btn btn-success" value="&#xf0d6; Cobrar"/>
```

Comment: Entiendo, estaba tratando en lo posible de utilizar Bootstrap porque es algo que no lo requiere, pero creo que me veré forzado a utilizarlo

Comment: @diego_vzla no es obligatorio emplear `bootstrap` , solo lo añadí para agregar estilos adicionales , solo con `font-awesome` debería funcionar

Comment: Perfectoo, muchas gracias.
Los post se colocan como solucionados aquí? o quedan abiertos?

Comment: @diego_vzla se debe marcar como aceptada la respuesta que soluciono su problema.

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cómo se supone o donde saco el &#xf0d6;? ¡No entiendo!

Answer (score 0):

```
   <button type="submit"  ><i class="icon-database" ></i>Guardar</button>
```

intenta con esto y me dices que tal

Comment: Así también funciona pero no existe una manera para realizarlo con la etiqueta Input type="submit" en vez de un button?

Comment: <?php $icono="<span class='icon-database'></span>" ?>
    <input type="submit" value="<?php echo $icono ?> Guardar">

Me refiero a algo como eso

Comment: si vas a usar ese boton fuera de un form te recomiendo usar input type ='submit', de lo contrario utiliza button aca puedes ver con mas detalle las diferencias https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#idx-control-7

Answer (score 0):

Puedes asignar una imagen de fondo directamente sobre la etiqueta input con la propiedad **background-image**

Este ejemplo funciona para mi:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ej</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        input[type='submit'] {
            padding: 5px;
            width: 100px;
            text-align: right;
        }
        .icon-database {
            background-image: url('https://path/to/your/img.png');
            background-size: auto 20px;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input class='icon-database' type="submit" value="Guardar">
</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Simple: